# Code in .cpp file

Tags: c++

I am beginner in C++ in Eclipse environment. Could you explain whats wrong with this code.

```
   #include "Shapes.h"

  Shapes::Shapes(float l, float w)
   {
            length = l;
            width = w;


   float calculateArea()
              {
               float area = length * width;
               return calculateArea;
              }
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

Things wrong with your code:

- You're not using the `area` variable in any way.
- One of your `}` is in the wrong place.
- Your `calculateArea` is probably a member function of `Shapes` and should as such be prefixed with `Shapes::`.
- You aren't using the member initializer list.
- Your indentation is inconsistent.

Comment: Just to beat this point to death, [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Extremely useful and often more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to add the class scope in the implementation of `calculatateArea`.
Your cpp code must look like

```
Shapes::Shapes(float l, float w)
{
   length = l;
   width = w;
}

float Shapes::calculateArea()
{
   float area = length * width;
   return area;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code should be:

```
   #include "Shapes.h"

   Shapes::Shape(float l, float w) : length(l), width(w) { }
   float Shape::calculateArea()
   {
       return this->length * this->width;
   }
```

I changed your constructor to use the constructor syntax. It is faster than the assignment you did before.

You should read this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

It even has the same exact example as you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Its a great place to find the solution.